# Why does <p> element style differently on two nearly identical HTML pages?

Tags: html, css

Two pages use the same CSS file and have almost the same content, yet on one all `<p>` elements have top and bottom margin by default while on the other they don't. Inspecting the elements in browser doesn't give any clues, since the margin is never explicitly declared. What causes those `<p>` elements to act differently (at least in Firefox, I haven't tested it in other browsers)?

Comment: @KunJ: This question is already grammatically correct. You've actually made it all wrong with your edits. You might want to refrain from editing other people's posts for grammar until you learn what really constitutes proper grammar. Oh and your formatting is wrong too. ` is not meant to be used for random highlighting of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spend ridiculous amount of time trying to solve the problem (using browsers inspector and firebug, checking the css file) with no luck, so then I've switched to comparing the html files line by line. The reason why those elements formated differently was in the very first line of one of the html files.

One file started with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

while the other did not and that was enough to change the default styling of html elements (such as p).

---

This is very likely caused by the fact that when DOCTYPE is missing the browser switches to [quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) to emulate <s>bugs</s> features of older browsers.

Comment: On a side note, you could use a file like reset.css to make all common browser's settings fix up. You can find more about it here:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: ... which should be a secondary step to, first and foremost, ensuring the use of a proper doctype as far as possible.